# query and manipulation of variables in shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I'm continuing to try and understand the basics of shiny. I am now trying to take a user input via a text box (`input$answer`), have a conditional test based on that input (`input$answer == "xyz"`), and generate outputs based on this condition (`if { <do stuff for correct answer> } else { <do stuff for incorrect answer> }`).

I think I got much of the basics down. I can get a user input, I have turned this into a reactive value so I can generate a query in an if-statement without getting an error. And I can use that user input to generate an output after the answer is submitted.

There are two problems though:

1. The query `(isolate(input$answer) == "Hello")` is never TRUE since the value of `isolare(input$answer)` always remains the value it is first assigned. In the current case that is "Enter text..." but the behavior doesn't change if I leave this blank (it just assumes "" as the value). If I change the statement to `if (isolate(input$answer) == "Enter text...")` the evaluation will always be TRUE. Why does this value not change even though in the subsequent `paste0("Your answer of ",input$answer, " is incorrect!") })` the value is updated correctly?
2. Is there a way to prevent the correct/incorrect evaluation at the startup of the server and only have it kick it when the submit button has been hit for the first time?

```
library(shiny)

#// Define UI for game ----
ui <- fluidPage(

     #// for query
     fluidRow ( 
     
          #// column width and title
          column(6, h3("Question"),
                 
               h4("Type the word `Hello`"),  
     
               #// Input: Text Box
               textInput("answer", h3("Text input"),
                          value = "Enter text..."),
     
               #// submit button to terminate the text input
               submitButton("Submit")
          
          ), #// end column
     
          #// column width and title
          column(6, h3("Evaluation"),

               #// Output: Text ----
               textOutput(outputId = "evaluation")  
          
          ) #// end column
      ) #// end fluidrow
) # end fluidpage

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) { 

     #// set up variables
     answer <- reactiveValues()

     #// logic for correct vs. incorrect
     if (isolate(input$answer) == "Hello") {
          #// correct counter up by one
          correct <- correct + 1
          counter <- counter + 1
          #// answer is correct
          output$evaluation <- renderText({ 
          paste0("Your answer of `",input$answer, "` is correct!") }) 
     } #// end if
     else {
          #// answer is not correct
          output$evaluation <- renderText({ 
          paste0("Your answer of `",input$answer, "` is incorrect!") }) 
          counter <- counter + 1
     } #// end else     

     #// stop app if count reaches number of games
     if (counter == num) stopApp()
     
} #// end server

# Run the app ----

counter <- 0
num <- 10
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're trying to perform a logical comparison on a value outside of a reactive context. In the environment of your comparison, `input$answer` has never changed.

Also, `answer <- reactiveValues()` does nothing, because you've never accessed `answer`.

Here's an approach with `reactiveValues` and `observeEvent`:

```
library(shiny)
#// Define UI for game ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  #// for query
  fluidRow ( 
    #// column width and title
    column(6, h3("Question"),
           h4("Type the word `Hello`"),  
           #// Input: Text Box
           textInput("answer", h3("Text input"),
                     placeholder = "Enter text..."),
           #// submit button to terminate the text input
           submitButton("Submit")
    ), #// end column
    #// column width and title
    column(6, h3("Evaluation"),
           #// Output: Text ----
           textOutput(outputId = "evaluation"),
           br(),
           textOutput(outputId = "trials")  
    ) #// end column
  ) #// end fluidrow
) # end fluidpage

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) { 
#// set up variables
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$counter <- -1
  values$correct <- 0
  num <- 10
  
  #// logic for correct vs. incorrect
  observeEvent(input$answer,{
    if (isolate(input$answer) == "Hello") {
    #// correct counter up by one
    values$correct <- values$correct + 1
    #// answer is correct
    output$evaluation <- renderText({ 
      paste0("Your answer of `",input$answer, "` is correct!") }) 
  } #// end if
  else {
    #// answer is not correct
    output$evaluation <- renderText({ 
      paste0("Your answer of `",input$answer, "` is incorrect!") }) 
  } #// end else     
  values$counter <- values$counter + 1  
  output$trials <- renderText({paste0("Trials: ",values$counter,"  Correct: ",values$correct)})  
  #// stop app if count reaches number of games
  if (values$counter >= num) stopApp()
  })
} #// end server
# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you. I think I see now how to define the variables and use them. If the variables are used just on the server side they can be used as usual. If they need to shuttle between UI and server they will have to be defined as a reactive and then can be addressed via the name$xyz call inside the shiny commands. If they are to be used in other functions (e.g. if) they need to be called with isolate. Finally, wrapping everything up in the` observeEvent(input$answer)` the whole bit will only be executed once for each time a new answer is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn your logic inside out a little when you move from normal R to Shiny. Everything you want to be reactive (i.e. change in response to a user input) needs to be within a reactive context (e.g. a `renderText`).

In this example your `if` statement is only actually being executed once, when the app is loaded. To have it work more like you want, try something along these lines:

```
    output$evaluation <- renderText({ 
        
        if (input$answer == "Hello") {
            #// correct counter up by one
            correct <- correct + 1
            counter <- counter + 1
            paste0("Your answer of `",input$answer, "` is correct!") 
        } #// end if
        else {
            #// answer is not correct
            counter <- counter + 1
            paste0("Your answer of `",input$answer, "` is incorrect!") 
        } #// end else     
        
    })
```

In answer to your second question, I suggest doing two things. The first is to change `value = "Enter text..."` to `placeholder = "Enter text..."` in your text input definition. This will let the app know that "Enter text" isn't a real answer. Then you can use `req(input$answer)` at the start of your `renderText` expression to halt execution unless the text field has actually been filled in.

Comment: Thanks! The `placeholder = "Enter text..."` does exactly what I think it should have done. And it explains why having 'value' there mucked everything up.